# MySQL - "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'" not working in my Java application

Tags: java, mysql, exception

When I run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'` in MySQL command line console it runs very fine, but when I run the same code in the Java application I'm working on it produces the following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
> column 'VARIABLES' in 'field list'

Here is my Java code:

```
ConnectionHelper.setDatabaseName('information_schema');

Statement statement = ConnectionHelper.getStatement();
ResultSet = statement.executeQuery ("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'");

String serverVersion = null;
while (resultSet.next()) {
    serverVersion = resultSet.getString(3);
}
```

The `ConnectionHelper` is just a class that creates and sets up a connection to any database passed as parameter to the `setDatabaseName()` method.

I've even tried not to set any database since the query runs in MySQL command line console even without selecting any database, but still produces the same error.

Please I really need help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try running this if you just want the DB version:

```sql
SELECT VERSION();
```

I tested this locally

```java
sql = "SELECT VERSION() AS version";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
     System.out.println(rs.getString("version"));
}
```

Result: `5.6.13`

---

You could also select any MYSQL variable like this:

```sql
SELECT @@version AS version;
```

The results of your original query on my machine is:

> ```sql
> 'innodb_version','5.6.13'
> 'protocol_version','10'
> 'slave_type_conversions',''
> 'version','5.6.13'
> 'version_comment','Source distribution'
> 'version_compile_machine','x86_64'
> 'version_compile_os','osx10.8'
> ```

So you could select each [*global variable*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-option-variable-reference.html) one by one like this:

```sql
SELECT @@version as version, 
       @@innodb_version as innodb_version, 
       @@verision_compile_os as version_compile_os
       @@protocol_version as protocol_version 
       @@version_compile_machine as version_compile_machine
.....
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding as soon as I supposed to, I was sick.

Comment: I really appreciate all your contributions, but which of these do you think would be the best, because apart from the mysql version I also intended to get the protocol version and server type

Comment: Both my answer and peterm's answer are more or less the same. He's directly accessing the table where the variables are stored `information_schema.global_variables` and I am using the shorthand notation for accessing global variables `@@<variable_name>`

Comment: Alright thanks so much, I have used the answer by MagicMan coz it seems shorter to me. Thankyou MagicMan.

Answer (score 7):

You may use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` and `SESSION_VARIABLES` [tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-variables-table.html) like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.global_variables 
WHERE variable_name LIKE '%version%';
```

Sample output:

```
|           VARIABLE_NAME |                       VARIABLE_VALUE |
|-------------------------|--------------------------------------|
|          INNODB_VERSION |                               5.5.32 |
|        PROTOCOL_VERSION |                                   10 |
|         VERSION_COMMENT | MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi |
|                 VERSION |                               5.5.32 |
| VERSION_COMPILE_MACHINE |                               x86_64 |
|      VERSION_COMPILE_OS |                                Linux |
|  SLAVE_TYPE_CONVERSIONS |                                      |
```

Here is **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/28338)** demo.

---

### UPDATE (based on your comments)

You can specify all variable names that you need with `IN` clause

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.global_variables 
WHERE variable_name IN ('version', 'hostname', 'port');
```

Sample output:

```
| VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_VALUE |
|---------------|----------------|
|       VERSION |         5.5.32 |
|      HOSTNAME |            db2 |
|          PORT |           3306 |
```

Here is **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/28527)** demo.

Comment: @Harmony Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Sorry for not responding as soon as I supposed to, I was sick.

Comment: I like your idea, but is there a way I can also get the server type?, like: localhost via TCP/IP  ?

Comment: See updated answer. You can specify all variable names you're interested in using `IN` clause.