# MySql SHOW VARIABLES is yielding no results

Tags: c#, mysql

After fighting with this for some time I tried even this very degenerate example (the correct one should be "SHOW VARIABLES like 'max_allowed_packet'") and it still fails:

```
String CommandText = "Show variables;";
MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, Connection);
    using (MySqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
        while (Reader.Read())
            return (int)Reader["Value"];
```

^c^ving the command text into the workbench produces the expected result for every query I have tried.  No matter what syntax I use for the show variables I get "Enumeration yielded no results" in the reader and of course it crashes trying to cast that to an integer.  Immediately before hitting this code there was a Change Database command done with the connection so it must be open.

I can't think of anything that could be wrong here that would allow the query to execute at all (it does figure out the field count should be 2 so it must have talked to the database) and yet not give me any results.

The suggested question certainly looks like mine but I already tried that case:

Select * from information_schema.global_variables where variable_name like 'max_allowed_packet'

and got the same result--nothing.  As before, copying the text out of the debugger and pasting it in the workbench yields the right result.  How can this one situation produce no results without producing a total failure?

Comment: What do you get googling combinations of your command, tags, missing tags (eg workbench) & error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL - SHOW VARIABLE LIKE '%version%' not working in my java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914319/mysql-show-variable-like-version-not-working-in-my-java-application)

Comment: Not a C# person so I'm making this up as I go but I am suspicious of `(int)` in `return (int)Reader["Value"];` if it means what I assume... because status variable valures are almost certainly strings of digits, not integers.

Answer (score 0):

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; should work with 5.6.17 or greater versions
or SHOW LOCAL VARIABLES if you are looking for session variables.